# Phone gap ios app - show pdf file with print/email options

Tags: iphone, ios, cordova, phonegap-plugins, pdf-viewer

I have a requirement to do the following task.

Inside a Phonegap iOS app, the user wants to view a pdf file after clicking a link which will load the pdf from the remote server.
And also user needs print, email functions with this document viewer.

So far I have tried following options.

1. Exit from the app when user click on the link and try to load the pdf throught the Safari. This is not working because user has to relogin for viewing the application.
2. Check with child-browser plugin. But it does not provide the options like print/email.

It'll be really great if some one can help on this who has similar experience.

Thanks